# Redshift JSON query strangeness

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm trying to query a Redshift table's field containing JSON.

This query runs fine:

```
select *
from daily_process.staging 
where source_id is null 
and json_extract_path_text( misc , 'sourceidlist' ) is not null 
and request_date >= '2015-11-10'
```

but adding a second json_extract_path_text clause causes a **JSON parsing error**

```
select *
from daily_process.staging 
where source_id is null 
and json_extract_path_text( misc , 'sourceidlist' ) is not null 
and json_extract_path_text( misc , 'sourceidlist' ) <> ''  <-- adding causes error
and request_date >= '2015-11-10'
```

Does anyone see something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the JSON type of `sourceidlist` field? Is `misc` a column of `daily_process.staging`? Some sample JSON data would be welcomed as well.

Comment: The problem appears to be truncated data in JSON fields, resulting in invalid JSON.